# Template Page Content Made Searchable

Tags: search, page-template, the-content

I'm migrating a client site over to a WordPress CMS. I made templates for each of the pages that would have static content: about us, facility, FAQs, etc.

The problem is that this content seems to be unsearchable (if that's the right term).  Is there an easy way to make this content available to an internal (not Google.com) search query (along with the rest of the content that is available on a blog)?

Should I have put this stuff (the copy) into the content editor and accessed it with the_content()?  Is that the best way?

As I'm finishing this I'm getting that "duh" feeling, but I'll post it anyway in case there are other ways that might help others doing the same.

Thanks very much.

Comment: Did you manage to get your template content searchable? How'd you go about it?

Answer (score 1):

By default WordPress cannot search in template content. You **should** import your content into the data base. The [plugin HTML Import 2](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/import-html-pages/) will help here.

Another option is a separate search engine with a parser that can read the complete HTML output. The [plugin Search Unleashed](http://urbangiraffe.com/plugins/search-unleashed/) for example supports [Apache Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/core/). That's probably too much for a small site or anyone not very experienced with Java.